# jquery code working on all other browsers except safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $(".assignments-input").width(assignment_width +"px")
});
```

so basically, this block of jquery code works on every other browser besides safari. Any idea why? from the look of it the rest of my jquery code works just fine. I also tried using the css() function but that also did not work. A little help please?

Comment: Have you checked the Safari console to see what error it shows when trying to run that function? Also, where is ``assignment_width`` declared? I'm hoping there's a variable somewhere?

Comment: Dexterians the variable is declared higher up in the code. How do you check the safari console? I didn't think safari had a console.

Comment: It definitely does. Just open up the dev tools like you would any other browser. Right click, inspect and choose the console. Otherwise, google how to enable it if that doesn't work.

Comment: Dexterians I found out how to do it. i get no errors in the console. Any other ideas?

Comment: Run the line manually in the console. See if it works. Add a ``console.log`` line etc and see. Try work out if it's the ``$(window).on('load',`` that isn't working or if its your ``$(".assignments-input").width(assignment_width +"px")`` that isn't.

Comment: just found out at least one problem. I looked at the sources and it had an outdated version of the main.js file I was using, which didn't have that function I included. Let me try to change that.

Comment: @b0b75 Also do `console.log($(".assignments-input").length);` before `$(".assignments-input").width(...`.  If it is < 1 then it didn't find anything.  You could also try `$().ready(function(){...})` instead of `$(window).on('load', function(){...})`.

Comment: Ok so I found out the problem was that for some reason safari was not updating the document every time I saved on vs code. After I restarted xampp, it worked. Thanks everyone

Comment: Ah yeah that ole chestnut. Nice job! Glad you got it working :) - I make it general rule now to always refresh/update the document on whatever browser I'm testing with to avoid this. Haha